# PySide for Python 2.7.2 ImportError DLL load failed on Win32

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyside

I'm trying to get PySide working for Python 2.7.2 on 32 bit windows XP.

[The official docs](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Setting_up_PySide) say to install Qt AND PySide.

[This pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide#installing-pyside-on-a-windows-system) seems to indicate I should only need to install PySide-1.2.0.win32-py2.7.exe from [here](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/pyside/).

I have tried installing PySide-1.2.0.win32-py2.7.exe both with and without also installing Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Windows (VS 2008, 235 MB). I have tried putting the PySide and Qt directories on my path. No matter what I do I can not import PySide.QtCore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

I uninstalled everything python & qt (including NINJA-IDE, which uses qt, just in case).

I reinstalled python 2.7.5 (was using 2.7.3).

I reinstalled PySide-1.2.0.win32-py2.7.exe

I can now import PySide.QtCore

Somewhere in the past I must have done something that made my interpreter think it knew where to look for a qt file ('QtCore.pyd' perhaps?) and unistalling everything / reinstalling fixed this. That's my guess.